# How can I set the CFBundleShortVersionString (aka MARKETING_VERSION) of a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have an Objective-C framework that I distribute via CocoaPods, Carthage, and Swift Package Manager. For the CocoaPods and Carthage versions, the `CFBundleShortVersionString` returns the value that I set in the `.pbxproj` file, but the Swift package one always returns `1.0`, which I assume is the default value when there is no `CFBundleShortVersionString`. Is there a way to set this in `Package.swift`?

This is how I read the value at runtime:

```swift
let bundle = Bundle(for: Radar.self)
let versionString = bundle.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
```